# c++: variadic nested maps aka dictionary

Tags: c++, dictionary, variadic, random-access

I'd like to have a container in cpp that kind of behaves like python dictionaries do, at least in the following regards:

- key-value structure (key might be restricted to a single type)
- variadic value type (might be restricted to some pod types[int, double, string])
- deeply nested (arbitrary depth, but not necessary dynamic)
- randomly accessed
- accessed type is stored type

So at best, the following example should work;

```
typedef DictionaryContainer<string, <int, string, bool>, 2> Dict;
Dict mydict; //key-type is string, value-type one of int, string or bool, nested to depth 2
mydict["a"] = 1;
mydict["b"] = true;
mydict["c"] = 'string';
mydict["d"] = Dict();
mydict["d"]["a"] = false;

std::any& dict_d_a = mydict["d"]["a"]; // stores a bool
std::string& dict_c = mydict["c"]; // possibly get<std::string>(mydict["c"])
```

Is there anything like this out there? I have found containers that allow storing arbitrary types, like `boost::variant` but they do not allow random access and recursively defined containers (as far as I have figured it out).

Is there not some implementation of a tree / map that can be used in such way?

Comment: Json libraries create types similar to that.

Comment: Do you *actually* need different instances to have different values, or could you use `struct Dict { int a; bool b; std::string c; struct { bool a; } d; };`?

Comment: The 5th bullet point is incompatible with the second point in C++. An expression has a static type, it can't vary based on runtime information

Comment: My implementation of `BaseDictionary`, inspired from `NSDictionary`
, support most of the required syntax and features. It also accepts various types for keys. But I can't share our code base.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, JSON or YAML containers (after parsing) are very much structured exactly like that, and I bet I can wrap the libraries in such way, that i can use them in this way. However, that is a whole library dependency, only to get at to this possibly stand-alone defined structure.

Comment: @Catelth yes i really intend to have a container (arbitrary size arbitrary content) and not a dedicated (possibly inflexible) class. The idea is to store configuration parameters in the container and propagate them through my code at runtime.

Comment: There a re no standard containers (out of the box) for that, you have to write yourself(`std::variant`, `std::map` might help in that regards), or found external library that fit your needs.